# Get ticker price within html class issue. Creating a stock ticker through InternetExplorer.application

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create my own ticker price. Now I'm trying to get the ticker prices for indexes and trust funds which complicates things. I want to access the ticker price for the following url: https://www.avanza.se/fonder/om-fonden.html/313047/norron-active-r

Now the issue is getting to the 180,05 ( under "NAV-kurs" ) ticket price which is under the HTML class"SText bold" ( right-clicking price and selecting view component ).

I can do individual stocks through yahoo finance through getelementbyid but how do I access the innertext for a HTML-class? I can't find any property that works in connection to getelementbyclassname which I tried.

Code below

```
Private Sub get_ticker()

Dim ie_app As InternetExplorer
Dim ie_doc As htmldocument
Dim ticker As String

Set ie_app = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie_app.Visible = True
ie_app.navigate ("https://www.avanza.se/fonder/om-fonden.html/313047/norron-active-r")

Do Until ie_app.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set ie_doc = ie_app.document

ticker = ie_doc.getelement <<---- gaah 
Debug.Print ticker



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reluctant to use Javascript at all you can try something like that.

Note: this code relies on early binding and requires both the Microsoft XML (v6.0) and Microsoft HTML Object Library to be ticked in your references.

```
Sub getPrice()

    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim XSText As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim elt As MSHTML.HTMLDivElement
    Dim parentElt As MSHTML.HTMLLIElement
    Dim myPrice As Single

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.avanza.se/fonder/om-fonden.html/313047/norron-active-r", False
        .send

        If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
            Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Else
            MsgBox "xhr error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    set xhr = Nothing

    Set XSText = doc.getElementsByClassName("XSText")

    For Each elt In XSText
        If InStr(elt.innerHTML, "NAV SEK") <> 0 Then
            Set parentElt = elt.parentElement
            myPrice = CSng(parentElt.getElementsByClassName("SText bold")(0).innerHTML)
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox myPrice

End Sub
```

Comment: It is thus not possible to go through getelementsclassname to get the price?

Comment: It is - you could just do myPrice = doc.getElementsByClassName("SText bold")(0).innerHTML. However if you want more consistent, reliably repeatable code, it is usually recommended to work out a better logic based on how the html page is structured and the relative position of the different elements of interest.

Comment: Hello again, I've been reviewing your code and may I ask what the false statement under MSXML2.XMLHTTP.Open exactly does? I'm reading from the MSDN and it says : varAsync[optional]
A Boolean indicator of whether the call is asynchronous. The default is True (the call returns immediately). If set to True, attach an onreadystatechange property callback so that you can tell when the send call has completed.

Is there any relationship between the .send and the false statement under .open?

Comment: Yes, synchronicity refers to how code execution behaves with regards to the exchange with the server that takes place as part of the HTTP request. Specifically and once the request has been sent, code execution can be told to stop until the response is received from the server - this is the synchronous way, with the Async argument of the Open method set to False. This has the disadvantage of freezing up code execution until the reponse is received so you can't execute any instruction in between the request and response reception, but has the merit of simplicity in VBA.

Comment: If you go the asynchronous way, then code execution never stops, and just jumps to the next instruction once the send instruction has been executed - regardless of the status of the server response. But then you need to put mechanisms in place to monitor the server response and catch it once it has arrived. This is essentially achieved using events. Take a look here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask three more questions? 

Why is it that the "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" object has a 2 in it? I assume the MSXML stands for : Microsoft XML , but why the 2? 

When I search for MSXML2.XMLHTTP.send to figure out more about it I get "send Method (IXMLHTTPRequest)" as a first result ( and the only relevant is seems ), how come? I don't really understand the mechanism behind all this I'm afraid.

And lastly, what is the difference between MSXML2.XMLHTTP and MSXML2.XMLHTTP60?

Answer (score 1):

Cheat - That page contains jQuery which is much nicer to use to select elements with no ID, E.g. tell it to look for a `div` of class `XSText` containing `NAV SEK` : `div.XSText:contains('NAV SEK')` and read the text of the next element:

```
...
Set ie_doc = ie_app.Document

''Create a new element in the document we can read from:
Dim tempInput As HTMLInputElement
Set tempInput = ie_doc.createElement("input")
tempInput.Type = "hidden"
tempInput.ID = "tempInput"

'' add it to the document
ie_doc.appendChild tempInput

'' use jQuery to lookup the value and assign it to the temp input
ie_doc.parentWindow.execScript("$('#tempInput').val($( ""div.XSText:contains('NAV SEK')"" ).next().text())")

'' read the value
msgbox tempInput.Value
```

Comment: Very helpful. Though I would like to focus on VBA as I'm quite  new to programming. Is your code above pure VBA or VBA + JQuery?

Comment: Then your best be would be to do something with `getElementsByClassName` as almost nothing on that page has an id

Comment: Its VBA, then VBA that runs a Javascript routine in the page

Comment: I assume the seocnd last lien is the javascript routine. I got as far as the getelementsbyclassname but there I don't know what to specify after..
When i write getelementsclassname + dot nothing relevant shows up. How can I get to the ticket price via getelementsclassname?